# Understating certificate authority nesting

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services

Given we have the following network/CA structure:

```
Win2K8R2 - Root CA - no idea where its' certificate is?

Win2K8R2 - Sub CA - obtained CA certificate from Root CA

Win2K8R2 - OWA 2010 (Basically, a Web Server) - obtained an SSL certificate from SubCA
```

A client connects to the OWA web site and get's a warning, that the authority that has issued a certificate is not in trusted store.

*Question:*

What is the secure way to obtain a root CA certificate to import it to a trusted CA store on a client machine, given that I have an admin access to a Root CA.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to naviagte to https:///CertSrv authenticate and then click on "Download a CA certificate, certificate chain, or CRL".

Another way is to connect to the CA server, start an MMC, add a "certificates" snap-in, point it to "computer account", navigate to "personal"\"certificates" and then export the root.

Edit: once you have the certificate, you can either import it directly on the target machine or distribute it across your whole domain using GPO.